# Pandas: create word cloud from a column with strings

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, pandas, word-cloud

I have a following `dataframe` with `string` values:

```
  text
0 match of the day
1 euro 2016
2 wimbledon
3 euro 2016
```

How can I create a `word cloud` from this column?

Comment: you mean literaly a word cloud like this: https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [tuple of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39172275/2901002) with frequencies, so use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with `list comprehension`:

```
tuples = tuple([tuple(x) for x in df.text.value_counts().reset_index().values])
print (tuples)
(('euro 2016', 2), ('wimbledon', 1), ('match of the day', 1))

#https://stackoverflow.com/q/38247648/2901002
cloud.generate_from_frequencies(tuples)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to get the `value_counts` but after that how do I generate the  fancy `word cloud`?

Comment: Hard question, because I cannot test it. But I found solution and add it to answer.

Comment: I found another solution - please [check](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28786534/2901002).